# getting undefined error even though the function is defined

Tags: php

I have a class(DaySummary*) with a static function that I've created:

```
public static function recursive_in_array($search, $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            if(is_array($item))
                return recursive_in_array($search, $item);
            elseif($search == $item)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Within the code in another function (not a static function in the class) I try to use this function by doing:

```
if(self::recursive_in_array('taanitE', $exceptions))
        echo 'it is';
    else 
        echo 'it isn"t';
```

But I get an error saying:

> Call to undefined function recursive_in_array()

Why do I get this error? The function is clearly defined!

*DaySummary is inherited from DayAnalyzer which is inherited from DayData.

Answer (score 2):

```
return recursive_in_array($search, $item);
```

change to

```
return self::recursive_in_array($search, $item);
```

Check here for more details : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: oh, didn't know I should include `self::` within the function as-well. Thanks a lot!